# Azure Function App Illegal character in query

Tags: azure-functions, ebay-api, illegal-characters

I am creating an function app for the specific purpose of getting information from Ebay and passing it elsewhere. Ebay will be redirecting a user to this app with a code parameter but because of the format of it, I am getting failures.

An example of what they send me is: http://localhost:7071/api/EbayRedirectOAuth?code=v^1.1#i^1#f^0#p^3#r^1#I

Then when I try to get the query parameter all I get is "v^1.1". I thought that maybe it just isn't saving the parameter correctly so I'll just get the whole URI. When I try that, I get this error:

> Executed 'Functions.EbayRedirectOAuth' (Failed,
> Id=8bb42bf4-ca21-463e-83a8-2cc274b5d419, Duration=97ms)
> [2021-11-12T19:05:31.459Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while
> executing function: Functions.EbayRedirectOAuth.
> System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure Exception: URISyntaxException:
> Illegal character in query at index 50:
> http://localhost:7071/api/EbayRedirectOAuth?code=v^1.1 Stack:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I cannot change what Ebay is sending me so I have to somehow deal with it in the function app. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Comment: I've found that the issue is because of the ^ character. Is there anyway I can force it to become encoded before hitting my function app?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a frustrating non-issue. A few hours after I deployed my app and just left it alone, I came back to it and tried again. The new url that Ebay used was encoded and my app worked as expected. Don't know why they had it sending un-encoded at first but it works now.